# why bash shell does not make any difference after executed?

Tags: bash, shell, openmpi

I'm working a small project which needs using OpenMPI to make "mpicc" work. 
I made a file make_cmd:

`#!/bin/bash`

`module load OpenMPI`

However, after executing ./make_cmd, I was told:

> mpicc: command not found

But if I just type on the command line: `module load OpenMPI`, then mpicc is working.

Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194893/why-cant-i-load-modules-while-executing-my-bash-script-but-only-when-sourcing) on neighbouring site.

Because `module` is an alias/shell function and not a binary program, it's not necessarily available in the non-interactive sub-shell that is created when you run your script. You could probably run `source make_cmd` though, as that will just run the commands in your current interactive shell. You could ditch the `#!/bin/bash` line in that case.